# How to cache on both client and the server in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

In my website I have some pages which need to be cached on both server and client.

```
[OutputCache(Location= OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, Duration=3600)]
```

But in the above attribute `ServerAndClient` option simply says **client or server** not client and server.

Other options are not even close. Is there a way to make caching on both client and server?

Comment: How does it show that it's OR?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen **The output cache can be stored only at the origin server or at the requesting...** the C# documentation says that

Comment: Do read the next sentence. It means proxy servers are not allowed to cache, but both client *and* server are.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So, I can assume it caches on both server **and** client?

Comment: Both are allowed and suggested to, but neither are forced to do that. Depends on implementation.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank you very much. I will check documentations in detail.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - "ServerAndClient - The output cache can be stored only at the origin server or at the requesting client. Proxy servers are not allowed to cache the response. " So I read that differently. While you assume the first sentence is talking about proxy servers based on the context of the second, I do not. I think the comments are unrelated. Additionally, I just tested it and it stores it on the client, but still makes the call to the server which returns a 304 UNMODIFIED.

Comment: What @ozgur and I are looking for is like the behavior of using the combined OutputCacheLocation.Server and OutputCacheLocation.Client so that the call is never made.